# iPhone get data from plist

Tags: objective-c

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I have read similar questions but I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem..

I am making an iPhone app that shows a list of notes in a table view, and user can add and delete note.

When I add a new note to a server, I get a plist which looks like this:

```
<plist>
    <dict>
        <key>success</key><true />
        <key>note</key><string>new note</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

After user taps the `add` button, I request a connection to the server, and I do,

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [resultData appendData:data];
}
```

and then

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSError *sendError;
    NSArray *result = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:resultData options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:&sendError];
    if([result count] > 0){
        for(NSDictionary *dict in result){
            for(NSDictionary *dict in result){
                // This gives me an error "objectForKey: unrecognized selector to instance"
                NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"success"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that `dict` may not be a dictionary, so I tried `NSLog(@"%@", dict);` and it shows just `success`. But, I still don't know how I can get the value of `success`.

Comment: @Manohar No, that's incorrect, and it doesn't even have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: @Manohar What? I don't see a single array in this property list. It's a dictionary.

Comment: I don't really have a plist. The plist is returned from the server when I add a new note. Should I do it instead of this? `NSArray *result = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:resultData options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:&sendError];` In that case, what should my plist name should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

.h File

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSDictionary *dict;
```

.m file

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *rootPath;

rootPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FILE_NAME" 
                                               ofType:@"plist"];

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:rootPath];    

dict = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

//NSLog(@"PLIST retrive:%@",plistXML);    
if (!dictLang) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
}
```

Get Value ::

```
NSLog(@" Success :: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"success"]);
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the method on `NSPropertyListSerialization` is - quite logically - the root object of the property list you receive. So `result` is an `NSDictionary` (I can't even imagine why you assume it's an array...!?). Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"success"]);
```

Comment: @kabichan Why don't you read my answer? I mean, **fully.** From its beginning to its end. When you use a for-in loop on a dictionary, it will enumerate the **keys**. You don't need any of that looping nonsense. Just use `result` as you would use any normal dictionary. And try to get some common sense, really. And read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:resultData options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:nil] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDicts = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:nil options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:nil];
    }
    else if ([[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:resultData options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:nil] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        NSMutableArray *tempDicts = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:nil options: NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:NULL error:nil];
    }
```